# How does browser manage session/cookie in communication?

Tags: cookies, browser

My question is how does browser use session/cookie when we access a website.

For example, we have a cookie of "hello-world.com" that stores our identity on our machine.
Assuming it is our second time visit the site.
The server side is very simple:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$uid]))
      echo "Hello".$uid;
  else
      echo "You don't have my cookie"
```

when we enter the url in browser, does the browser go to our local "cookie base" to find the cookies associate with hello-world.com, and attach it automatically with our initial request?

if it is the case, Shouldn't we have some security concern? 
We send the information without being asked.

Also, how does browser know which cookie to send?

Comment: Take a look in your browser's network inspector. For every request your browser ever makes, it sends all the cookies it has for that domain as part of the request. As it's only sending the cookies for **that** domain, there's not a security issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz , thanks for your answer.